how to download snap store latest version in ubuntu 24.04
i downloaded Ubuntu 24.04 on my dekstop and by mistake i deleted the snap store and when i am using the command , sudo snap install snap-store  to install the snap store the latest version is not which is with 24.04 is not downloaded. guide me on how to download the latest version

What does snap list show? you can always update snaps with sudo snap refresh

Use code below to restore default snap-store in 24.04
sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04


snap info snap-store should show you all versions available.  If you see version 41.3-77-g7dc86c8 on your installed, then you are running the newest version.
:~$ snap info snap-store
name:    snap-store
summary: Snap Store is a graphical desktop application for discovering,
  installing and managing snaps on Linux.
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/snap-store
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/
license:   unset
description: |
  Snap Store showcases featured and popular applications with useful
  descriptions, ratings, reviews and screenshots.
  
  
  Applications can be found either through browsing categories
  or by searching.
  
  
  Snap Store can also be used to switch channels, view and alter snap
  permissions and view and submit reviews and ratings.
  
  
  Snap Store is based on GNOME Software, optimized for the Snap experience.
commands:
  - snap-store
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software
  - snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
snap-id:      gjf3IPXoRiipCu9K0kVu52f0H56fIksg
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 2024-03-06
channels:
  latest/stable:     41.3-77-g7dc86c8 2024-03-06 (1113) 13MB -
  latest/candidate:  41.3-77-g7dc86c8 2024-03-05 (1113) 13MB -
  latest/beta:       ↑                                       
  latest/edge:       0+git.5c11cdf    2024-06-14 (1151) 10MB -
  preview/stable:    –                                       
  preview/candidate: 0.2.7-alpha      2023-02-02  (864) 10MB -
  preview/beta:      ↑                                       
  preview/edge:      0.3.0-alpha      2023-08-14 (1017) 11MB -

